# Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am randomly selecting an id using an and using it to manipulate the CSS.
But I am getting an error as

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
>   (anonymous function) @ ReactionTester.html:101

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Reaction Tester</title>

<style type="text/css">

    #box {
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        display: none;
    }

    #circle {
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        border-radius: 100px;
        display: none;
    }

    #score {
        display: none;
    }

</style>

</head>

<body>


<p id="score">Your reaction time was <span id="reaction"></span></p>
<div id="box"></div>
<div id="circle"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

           var shapes = ["box", "circle"];
           var shape = Math.random();
           shape = 2 * shape;
           shape = Math.floor(shape);
           var finalShape = (shapes[shape]);
           console.log(finalShape);

           var createdTime;
           var clickedTime;
           var reactionTime;



           function getColor() {

               var colors = ["#0E7AC4", "#f1c40f", "#9b59b6", "#e74c3c", "#f39c12", "#c0392b", "#2c3e50", "#59ABE3",
                       "#6BB9F0", "#26A65B", "#65C6BB", "#86E2D5", "#4DAF7C", "#F5D76E", "#FDE3A7", "#F9BF3B",
                       "#FDE3A7", "#F4D03F", "#EB9532", "#F2784B", "#F5AB35", "#F9BF3B", "#ABB7B7"
               ];

               var color = Math.random();

               color = colors.length * color;

               color = Math.floor(color);

               console.log(color);

               return colors[color];

           }



           function makeBox() {


               createdTime = Date.now();

               var color = getColor();

               console.log(color);

               document.getElementById('finalShape').style.backgroundColor = color;

               var time = Math.random();

               time = 5000 * time;

               time = Math.ceil(time);

               console.log("Coming in : " + time);

               setTimeout(function() {

                   document.getElementById('finalShape').style.display = "block";

               }, time);

           }

  ***Error shows up here*** document.getElementById('finalShape').onclick = function() {

               this.style.display = "none";
               clickedTime = Date.now();

               reactionTime = clickedTime - createdTime;

               document.getElementById('score').style.display = "block";
               document.getElementById('reaction').innerHTML = (reactionTime / 1000) + " seconds";

               makeBox();

           }

           makeBox();

    </script>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('finalShape')
```

Looks for the element literally named finalShape (and since there is none, returns null, and the error says you cant set an clickhandler on that), you want to use the variable finalShape, like so:

```
document.getElementById(finalShape)
```

Comment: I have a question. If use finalShape as a variable not as a text, when there are values so returns element, then does it work?

Comment: @liming. Could you try to write that question in another way? The last part is not clear. " when there are values so returns element, then does it work?"

Comment: @liming if you have an element named potato (id="potato") in your html and have assigned that value to the variable finalShape (var finalShape = 'potato') then this code would get the element with the id potato.